# I am getting an redifinition error in the cpp file, can anyone please say, how to fix it?

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef SORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define SORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED

const int MAX_ITEMS = 5;

template <class T>
class SortedType
{
 public :
   SortedType();
   void MakeEmpty();
   bool IsFull();
   int  LengthIs();
   void InsertItem(T);
   void DeleteItem(T);
   void RetrieveItem(T&, bool&);
   void ResetList();
   void GetNextItem(T&);

 private:
  int length;
  T info[MAX_ITEMS];
  int currentPos;
};
#endif // SORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED



#include "sortedtype.h"

template <class T>
SortedType<T>::SortedType()
{
 length = 0;
 currentPos = - 1;
}

template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::MakeEmpty()
{
 length = 0;
}

template <class T>
bool SortedType<T>::IsFull()
{
 return (length == MAX_ITEMS);
}

template <class T>
int SortedType<T>::LengthIs()
{
 return length;
}

template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::InsertItem(T item)
{
    int location = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(info[location]<item)
            location++;
    else
        break;
    }
    for(int i=length; i>location;i--)
    {
        info[i]=info[i-1];
    }
    info[location]= item;
    length++;
}
template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::DeleteItem(T item)
{
    int location=0;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(info[i] == item)
            break;
        location++;
    }
    for(int i=location; i<length; i++)
    {
        info[i] = info[i+1];
    }
    length--;
}

template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::RetrieveItem(T& item, bool &found)
{
    int first=0, last=length-1, mid;
    while(first<=last)
    {
        mid=(first+last)/2;
        if(info[mid]== item)
        {
            found=true;
            return;
        }
        if(info[mid]<item)
        {
            first=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            last=mid-1;
        }
    }
    found=false;
}

template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::ResetList()
{
 currentPos = - 1;
}

template <class T>
void SortedType<T>::GetNextItem(T& item)
{
 currentPos++;
 item = info [currentPos];
}
```

I am getting a redefinition error in the cpp file, can anyone please say, how to fix it?
I have tried all the possible things.
I am not getting what mistake have I done.
After building its just saying "error: redefinition of 'SortedType::SortedType()'"
and same thing for all the other functions.
What things can remove this error?
What changes can be done to fix it.
I have posted the code which I have written.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: I'd rather except a redefinition of `MAX_ITEMS`. Can you copy and paste full error message into the question?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], other than templates generally needing to be implemented in the header file (which will produce a different error when it comes to linking your program) your code looks OK and [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/eGxzfx)

Comment: Are you including the .cpp file in another .cpp file?   If that somehow happens more than once in some other .cpp file, that might explain your problem.

Comment: What is the #include "sortedtype.h" doing?  What is the name of the file you have shown?  if it is "sortedtype.h", you are recursing a header file, which would be very strange construction.

Comment: Never mind.  I guess you have run the header file and the cpp file together...

Comment: This whole class can be put in the .h file (take out the #include "sortedtype.h" and make this whole section of code a .h file)  Then include the .h file in the code file(s) where you want to use the class, and it should build fine.  I tested in MSVC 17 and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that are defined within a header, have to be `inline` otherwise you get a redefinition error if they are used in multiple translation units.

If you define a member function within the body of the class then the member function is implicitly marked `inline`. If you define it outside of the class body, like in your example then you need to mark it `inline` explicitly, by adding the `inline` keyword in front of it.